# git checkout --track failed

Tags: git, debian, buildroot

I have cloned the buildroot git repository (https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot) into a local repository on my host developement machine running Debian Stretch.

Everything's fine and the output of `git remote -v` is :

> origin    https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot (fetch)
>
> origin    https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot (push)

Now i list the repo tags using `git tag` and want to checkout on the last tag (currently 2018.02) and create the local branch at the same time.

if i use `git checkout -b 2018.02 2018.02` it works but if i use `git checkout --track origin/2018.02` it fails with :

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '2018.02' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/2018.02' which can not be
>   resolved a s commit?

How to fix this error ?

Note : my git version is 2.11.0.

Thank you.

Comment: The `--track` option makes no sense when checking out a tag. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Read about [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout). Its use cases and the arguments it expects in each case are explained there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `git checkout -b 2018.02 2018.02` does indeed work, for reasons you might not be expecting.

First, read through [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), which describes the normal process by which Git turns a name into a commit hash:

> *<refname>*, e.g., *master*, *heads/master*, *refs/heads/master*
>
>   A symbolc ref name. ... When ambiguous, a
>   *<refname>*
>   is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:

(and then it lists six rule steps).  In your case you are giving Git the name `2018.02` (as the final argument to `git checkout`), when the only reference name that matches is `refs/tags/2018.02`—the *branch* name `refs/heads/2018.02` does not exist (not yet!).

So, Git resolves the tag, ultimately finding commit hash ID `8a94ff12d232ada68cff5957089a78a1f0b8f192`, and checks out that commit.  As it does so, it *creates* a branch named `2018.02`, so that after the `git checkout` finishes, `refs/heads/2018.02` *also* exists.

Now there is a problem: the reference name is ambiguous.  Does `2018.02` mean the *tag name* `2018.02`?  Or does it mean the *branch name*?

Read that same sentence, the one just before the six steps, again:

> ... When ambiguous, a *<refname>* is disambiguated by taking the **first match** in the following rules:

The *first* match is the one that adds `refs/tags/` in front of the name, so most commands, asked about `2018.02`, will *still* refer to commit `8a94ff12d232ada68cff5957089a78a1f0b8f192`, regardless of what happens with your branch name.

The `git checkout` command does not obey the six steps: if you say `git checkout 2018.02`, Git looks *first* for `refs/heads/2018.02`.  If that exists, Git checks out the *branch name*, by attaching your `HEAD` to `refs/heads/2018.02` and checking out whichever commit that name identifies.  If you've made a few new commits since creating the branch name, that will be some other commit—not `8a94ff12d232ada68cff5957089a78a1f0b8f192` at all.

Most other Git commands will locate the tag name.  Back up one more sentence and consider:

> If you happen to have both *heads/master* and *tags/master*, you can explicitly say *heads/master* to tell Git which one you mean.

This applies to your name `2018.02` as well: you can write out `tags/2018.02` to mean the tag name, and `heads/2018.02` to mean the branch name.  But it's wiser not to get into the situation in the first place: choose some other branch name and there's no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @Scab: you have the names reversed here, it's `git checkout -b <new-name> <existing-commit-specifier>` so this would be `git checkout -b branch-2018.02 2018.02`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that. I have deleted my comments to make things more clear.